# Как имитировать некоторые действия

Tags: c#, распознавание-речи, microsoft-speech-sdk

Помогите имитировать клик, х2 клик, правый клик, CTRL+V в C#. У меня программа голосовое управление, надо чтобы эти действия обезательно были.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду чтобы программа вызывала эти события по голосовой команде? Не совсем понятно, конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Скажем когда пользователь скажет "Клик", тогда программа будет имитировать клик.  Или когда скажет "Ставить", имитировалась CTRL+V в активном окно.

Comment: Добавьте обработчик событий и вызывайте его по команде, это конечно на ответ не тянет, но хотя бы наводка где "копать"

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov нашол ответ,  SendKeys.Send("^(v)");

Answer (score 0):

Нашол ответ. Спс Всем
SendKeys.Send("^(v)");

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/256986)

Comment: Как вы видите тут нет других ответов кроме моего. Я так хотель сказать другим(кто будет отвечать ), что ч уже нашол ответ!